# Android - Alternative to async tasks?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

So I have an app in which I use an async task to fetch in data from a Django backend using rest API. This will be used the first time when the device needs to be synced with the site. 
So this sync task fetches in quite a lot of data (2 GB). And I have read in many places that async tasks really should be used when the process takes not more than 2-3 seconds. Definitely gonna take longer in my case.

1. So what is my alternative here? Handlers? Can someone point to a tutorial or article explaining how to?
2. During the sync process, my device turns off the display to save power. Hence the activity gets destroyed. Now after the sync is complete I show a dialog box, using "AlertDialog" class, informing the user of the same. This causes an error: Activity has leaked a window. Is it a serious issue? What can be done to avoid that? Use fragments to show dialog boxes?

Comment: "nd I have read in many places that async tasks really should be used when the process takes not more than 2-3 seconds". I dont see why. Could you post some references to this "many place" ? AsyncTask is backend by an ExcetuorService. You can always sublcass Thread as alternative

Comment: I would maybe think of implementing the sync as a service if it is supposed to happen more often. That way you don't really need to care about what the application does. However I'm a noob when it comes to android development so someone may have a better answer for you...

Comment: great question, check this out https://github.com/octo-online/robospice

Comment: @blackbelt it says so in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @nOiAd - I checked out robospice. Although it appears to be very very useful and solves my problem, but it also appears to be an overkill for my current scenario. They have some wonderful explanation of the whole process and some good samples too. But what I think they lack is a sample for the simplest scenario: An activity that uses an asynchronous network request to perform a long running network operation and gets updated with the progress. At least I couldn't find it in their repo and wiki. I think I may use it in future if I have a more complex requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).
It's meant for long-running tasks and is not tied to your Activity lifecycle.
It would be especially helpful for the user if you'd also associate a notification with the download, showing the progress (as 2GB can take a huge amount of time to fetch, especially on a mobile connection. Speaking of that - please don't fetch 2GB of data on a mobile connection without making it really clear to the user that you're going to do that or enabling them to opt-out of this or do it only when connected over WiFi. Data-limited users will thank you ;)
[Here's a tutorial about services](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Or you can let the OS take care of all of this and use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to fetch the file. It takes care of device restarts, connection issues etc.
[Sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/Download), [Tutorial](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/)

Comment: No the download won't occur unless the user is connected to wi-fi. It's also going to be a one time download only and of course with the user's approval.

Comment: Thanks. I had to create a simple custom service to achieve this. Can't use download manager because I have to write to internal memory [Ya. 2 GB of content to internal memory. don't ask why :( ]. Now I have a question though. I have to leave the service registered in my activity. I can't unregister it because I need my activity to be able to receive messages from the service even when the screen goes off to save power. Question: is it harmful from a memory leak perspective?

Comment: So I found out the answer to my question in the previous comment. I was a bit confused between the service and the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use IntentService for performing long running task in background. It will also finished automatically after completing the job.