# AsyncTask Alternative or Interface

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I am looking for an alternative to AsyncTask so I can use it(I'm already extending class from Activity) What I'm trying to do is ping to google. Since I can not do it in main thread and can not extend from another class. So what are my options?
     I googled and found a Service class but the page Here (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html/)! says It is not a thread and is not used to avoid "Not Responding" (as I mentioned earlier I am trying to access Internet)
I am using android JellyBeans

Comment: You can start a service and then start a separate thread in that service.

Comment: But what about <is not used to avoid "Not Responding">?
Wouldn't this be prone to errors?

Comment: Instead of a creating a `Service` and start a `Thread` on it, you can use `IntentService` which does automatically.

Comment: No need for a Service for that simple task.

Comment: refer to service 

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19858765/2367851

Comment: As @Emmanuel said there are a number of options including IntentService. You had mentioned a service so I thought there might be something else you wanted to do with the service. The Not Responding issue has to do with how you setup your service/thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an anonymous class, basically a class inside another one. More specifically, you need an anonymous subclass of `AsyncTask` in your `Activity`. An alternative would be to create a subclass of `AsyncTask` and pass the variables you need as arguments.

There should be no need for making a class subclass of two classes. Rethink your concept.

Comment: The problem with `AsyncTask` inside an `Activity` is that he will be bound to the `Activity` lifecycle. Putting the `AsyncTask` inside a `Fragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)` might be a decent way to avoid lifecycle conflicts.

Comment: Yes, but you should not need more for a simple ping.

Comment: You are correct, but what if the single ping takes long and the `Activty` is destroyed for some reason (i.e. he rotated the device and there is no coverage). He would have to manually cancel the task accordingly.

Comment: Exactly. The alternative would be to get the result at a point where it is no longer relevant to the user.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong conceptually but I am trying for the class to launch an the layout. Is it not necessary to extend from Activity while launching a layout.xml? if not then I'd not extend but I think it is... So how am I to reconsider my concept? (not taunting but simply asking)

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, you need the `Activity`. But that does not mean you cannot use an `AsyncTask` inside that `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this post, there is explanation about an alternative for async task

[Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858765/2367851)